# "AccessControlException" when trying to unmarshall an external page using JAXB in App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jaxb

So I'd like to read Facebook's locales page and store it in a datastore for use by our app running on Google's App Engine.

I create a URL like this:

```
URL facebookXmlUrl = new URL( "https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml" );
```

I create my unmarshaller like this:

```
JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance( FacebookLocales.class );
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxb.createUnmarshaller();
```

(Note: The **FacebookLocales** class pretty mirrors their XML and marshalls to look just like it.)

When I actually try the unmarshall:

```
FacebookLocales fbLocales = ( FacebookLocales ) unmarshaller.unmarshal( facebookXmlUrl );
```

I get the following error (even/esp. on the local, development app engine):

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.xml.bind.JAXBPermission" "setDatatypeConverter")
```

I've Googled my little heart out but haven't found anything to help.

Comment: Have you tried the unmarshal method on `facebookXmlUrl.openStream()`? Can you open the stream? I read somewhere that GAE is a little stringent on opening URLs.

Comment: It is also possible your `FacebookLocales` has an error. Does it have any private methods?